# For every positive integer $m$ there exists $k\in \mathbb N$ such that $(m-n)^2>m^2$ for all $n>k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm having a lot of difficulty trying to prove the following statement. I have asked a few classmates however they aren't sure either.

$$\forall m\in\mathbb N: \exists k\in\mathbb N \ni (m-n)^2>m^2\forall n>k $$

My best idea was to take the negation then use a proof by contradiction  to prove the original statement.

Any thoughts or advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: $(m-n)^2=(n-m)^2$.  So we can instead find a value of $k$ (as a function of $m$) for which $n>k$ implies $(n-m)^2 > m^2$?

Comment: Thank you. I think I am getting closer. I think if k is greater than zero then the statement must be true.

Comment: K must be. Greater than zero to satisfy the proof, though I am not sure how this proves the statement

Comment: We have freedom to choose $k$, and we can choose it as a function of $m$.  If we attempted to choose $k=m$, then we would have $(m-n)^2=(n-m)^2>(k-m)^2=0 \not>m^2$, so this doesn't work.  The task is to find $k$ so that $(m-n)^2>m^2$ when $n>k$.

Comment: I think all values of k greater than zero will work, I am plugging in and testing this theory

Comment: Wait hmm, k should be 2m and that makes a lot more sense

Comment: But it is actually proven at this point? I feel that there is something missing

Comment: Basically it is, if we choose $k=2m$, we just need to verify that $(m-n)^2>m^2$ whenever $n>2m$, which is just arithmetic.

Comment: Ohh I see, interesting. Thank you so much for your help!